# Почему не меняются права?

Tags: laravel, unix, chown

Почему не меняются права?

> UnexpectedValueException The stream or file
> "/var/www/bossphp.x/storage/logs/laravel-2020-07-06.log" could not be
> opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
>
> сhown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/bossphp.x
>
> Command 'сhown' not found, did you mean:
>
> command 'chown' from deb coreutils
>
> Try: sudo apt install

Comment: Потому что буква «с» в вашей команде сhown русская, а должна быть английская

Comment: поменял на английскую и все файлы стали в замке и не для редактирования

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/bossphp.x/storage
    но потом все равно при создании нового лага требует опять прописывать это

    уже надоело это делать
    как сделать один раз?